# How to update an object in the redux store?

Tags: redux

I want to add items in the object in the redux store one after the other as the user progresses in the application. Therefore, I want to add items in the store without removing the previous items in the store.

Please refer the code below:

Code for the reducer:

```
const currentTravelPlanDefaultState = {};

export default (state = currentTravelPlanDefaultState, action) => {

    switch(action.type){
        case 'ADD_PLAN': 
        return {
            ...state,
            currentTravelPlan: {
                ...state.currentTravelPlan,
                ...action.currentTravelPlan
            }
        }
        default:
        return state;
    }
};
```

Code for the action:

```
import uuid from 'uuid';

export const addTravelPlan = (details) => ({
    type: 'ADD_PLAN',
    currentTravelPlan: {
        id: uuid(),
        details
    }
});
```

Code for the disptach calls:

```
store.dispatch(addTravelPlan({destination: 'Cuba'}));
store.dispatch(addTravelPlan({hotel: 'Cuba Grand'}));
store.dispatch(addTravelPlan({travelMode: 'AirWays'}));
```

However, it appears that only the last item is added in the store which is the airways and the previous items are not persisted.

Please help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should map state to props first, get all the data from the redux state and then add on what data you want. Combine them to an object and dispatch that object to the reducer

Comment: what is your expected data in redux store?

Comment: I believe you are saying to add all the items together to the redux store. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @eramit2010 the currentravelplan object in the redux store must have all the three items i.e. destination, hotel and travelmode.

Comment: you might need to destructure details in your action {id: uuid(), ...details }

Comment: Ohkay will try that and is my reducer code correct?

Comment: you should add empty currentTravelPlan object inside your default state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want your data to look like this after the dispatch calls:

```
currentTravelPlan: {
  id: uuid(),
  destination: 'Cuba',
  hotel: 'Cuba Grand',
  travelMode: 'Airways'
}
```

In that case, your action code should be:

```
export const addTravelPlan = (details) => ({
    type: 'ADD_PLAN',
    currentTravelPlan: {
        id: uuid(),
        ...details
    }
});
```

and your reducer:

```
const currentTravelPlanDefaultState = {};

export default (state = currentTravelPlanDefaultState, action) => {

    switch(action.type){
        case 'ADD_PLAN': 
          return {
            ...state,
            ...action.currentTravelPlan
          }

        default:
          return state;
    }
};
```

Comment: Please don't post plagiarised content. Copied content needs original author attribution. See [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing). I've rolled back to copied content.

Answer (score 0):

In reducer you should set currentTravelPlan to empty object so you know how your state going to look.

```
const currentTravelPlanDefaultState = {
    currentTravelPlan: {}
};

export default (state = currentTravelPlanDefaultState, action) => {

switch(action.type){
    case 'ADD_PLAN': 
    return {
        ...state,
        currentTravelPlan: {
            ...state.currentTravelPlan,
            ...action.currentTravelPlan
        }
    }
    default:
    return state;
}
```

};

in your action you are passing data wrongly. you need to destructure details before sending it. if you don't destructure it will always pass details: your object

```
import uuid from 'uuid';

export const addTravelPlan = (details) => ({
    type: 'ADD_PLAN',
    currentTravelPlan: {
        id: uuid(),
        ...details
    }
});
```